# Petstore -Swagger : sending request in XML format and reponse getting a TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Pet')

Tags: json

**Postman Body:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Pet>
    <id>0</id>
    <Category>
        <id>0</id>
        <name>Dog</name>
    </Category>
    <name>Jimmy</name>
    <photoUrls>
        <photoUrl>string</photoUrl>
    </photoUrls>
    <tags>
        <Tag>
            <id>0</id>
            <name>string</name>
        </Tag>
    </tags>
    <status>available</status>
</Pet>
```

**Test Validations:**

```
pm.test('Check Pet Name',() =>
{
    let jsonData1=xml2Json(responseBody); //convert xml to json data
    pm.expect(jsonData1.Pet.name).to.eq("Jimmy");
})
```

Error:
When sending a request getting a error message:

sending request in XML format  and reponse getting a TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Pet')